# Annotations on a realtime LineSerie graph

Tags: c#, wpf, graph, annotations, oxyplot

I'm using Oxyplot to plot a realtime Line graph (X axis is DateTimeAxis and Y axis is LineAxis) with several lines. All works well.

Now, I want to show on screen the `Minimum` and `Maximum` of each LineSerie in the graph. Firstly, I thought this would be easy to achieve with `TextAnnotation`, but as my X axis moves every second, my annotation simply goes away. I would like it to stay still at the same position on screen.

Is there a way I can do it without having to update its position everytime the plot refreshes? Actually, the main problem isn't the refresh itself, but the ability to pan without affecting the annotation.

In an older version, I was using `TextAnnotation.NeedTransform = false`, but this seems to be taken out in the newer version of the library.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why you dont want to update the annotation position if you are refreshing constanly? I mean, why not to put the updated annotation in the refresh routine, if it is refreshing the whole plot...

Comment: @Kirenenko I would like to use an annotation that would have the same position on screen regardless of me panning (with the right-mouse button) the plot. Nevertheless, I've come up with another approach that satisfied my needs (appending the info in the line title and showing in the legend).